# I have a quick question on 2-1 multiplexers

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

So say we have a 2-1 MUX with

- \$D_0=GND\$,
- \$D_1=Q_0\$ and
- S=X.

Questions:

- The output equation will be \$Q_0X\$, correct?
- Now if we change \$D_0\$ to Vdd instead of GND, what happens?

If X=1 the output will be \$Q_0\$, but if X=0 the output will just be logical 1.

Would the equation be \$Q_0X+\bar{X}\$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your logic is correct.

The output, `Z`, of the mux is `Z = (D1 and S) or (D1 and S')`.

If `D0` is held at `GND` then `Z = (D1 and S)`. If `D0` is held at `+Vdd` then `Z = (D1 and S) or (S')`.